# WPDeals Add custom currency

Tags: plugins

I'm using WPDeals plugin and need to add a custom currency.

Here is what I have found so far:

```
add_filter( 'deals_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
$currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'wpdeals' );
return $currencies;
}

add_filter('deals_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
switch( $currency ) {
case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break;
}
return $currency_symbol;
}`
```

But I have no idea where to insert this code, or how to modify it to work.

Could someone please provide an example, and which file to edit.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while, but I found the solution. I decided to write a blog post on it. 
http://readmystuff.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/how-to-add-a-new-currency-to-wpdeals-the-real-way/

Comment: Thank you for letting us know what worked. Please click the check mark by your answer to approve it.